# reorder models in unity folder by dateTime in C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-editor

I have different bulk (400 around) amount of FBX which are placed in `Assets/Model` folder. Now these FBX are usually update regularly.

1. After updating the FBX
2. I have to bring them in `scene hierarchy` then,
3. I make some settings on those objects
4. and then finally I make prefab of every model from scene hierarchy.

   Now the problem is that I don't know which FBX has updated and which is old. So that i can use new FBX only and make prefab of it. The question is that is there any way avaible that i reorder my fbx by datetime in my assets folder (Project tab).? So that i can get the latest fbx on top. Or maybe some better alternate to mange it?

Comment: It sounds like you'd be much better off to automate this with a script. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PrefabUtility.html

Comment: Thanks for the recommendations i have partially automated the process. But i have to still bring the object in scene hirarchy in order to apply some settings of LoD and layering.

Comment: You may be able to automate that too. We don't use fbx specifically, but we do automate all of our importing with a combination of https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetPostprocessor.html and other editor scripts.